# Reading function definitions in C

Tags: c, function, definition

I'm a Java dev, and for some reason I'm studying C at the moment. The thing is I'm having some trouble reading function definitions. Could you give me a hint with this one for instance:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void(*func)(int)))(int)
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should learn the [right-to-left rule](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/complex_declarations.aspx). This page contains good examples.

`signal` is a function taking as arguments:

- an integer
- a pointer to function taking `int` and returning nothing

and returning a pointer to a funcction taking `int` and returning nothing.

Comment: Lookup 'cdecl' on the web.  BTW signal is one of the more convoluted examples.  :-)

Comment: thanks a lot man! Couldn't actually think that a function could return a function in that way. Thanksss!

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore: actually pointers to functions are what make it possible to have some alternative to inheritance in C. In C++ you better use a base pure virtual functior and you intantiate a derived class which implements your function. I thought Dumbledore knew everything.

Comment: Thanks Benoit! I know that polymorphism in C++ is implemented through pointers to functions. :-) And, yes, the real Dumbledore *does* know quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks Benoit. After reading the referred article, I could read the prototype, too! I am so happy now :-)

Answer (score 2):

*func* is a pointer to a function which takes an int and returns void.

*signal* is a function which takes an int and a pointer like func and returns a pointer like func.

That is: you specify which signal handler (*func*) associate to the signal (*sig*), and the function returns a signal handler (the previous one) which you can store somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

An example of 'cdecl' in action.  I think its available for Linux or source can be downloaded & built.

```
cdecl> explain char *(*fptab[])()
declare fptab as array of pointer to function returning pointer to char
cdecl>
```

Comment: cdecl is useful... maybe you could have tested it on signal itself? :-)

Comment: Thanks David. cdecl can indeed explain some stuff!!! Never dreamed of such a tool. However, it couldn't explain may definition, i.e. it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: Gosh, never though that this cdecl could be what wikipedia says it's so. So C is indeed close to assembly in some ways?

Comment: @Albus.  Depends on your perspective. ;-)  No.  There is the 'cdecl' utility short for 'C Declare' AFAIK versus some X86 calling convention also called 'cdecl' which *is* on wikipedia.   BTW I think Van Lindens approach to unscrambling declarations is better than just 'right to left'.

Comment: Here is Van Linden's version of signal:  _signal is a function (with some funky arguments) returning a pointer to a function (taking an int argument and returning void). One of the funky arguments is itself: void (*func)(int) ; a pointer to a function taking an int argument and returning void."_     **'Deep C Secrets', Peter Van Linden**

Comment: Thanks David. I'll certainly look for the book. :-) Meanwhile I'll use the free article that Benoit offered.